# Как протестировать объект, который вызывает внутренний метод

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mocking, moq

Вот код:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

public class Collector
{
    private string folder;

    public Collector(int _id)
    {
        this.folder = $@"~/Files/{_id}/collector";
    }
    public void UpdateCollectorSchoolIds()
    {
        var folderSchoolIds = GetFolderSchoolIds(folder);
        /*
         здесь происходит обработка коллекции folderSchoolIds
         */
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> GetFolderSchoolIds(string folder)
    {
        var assumedFolderSchoolIds = Directory.GetFiles(folder).ToList()
                                              .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x).Substring(0, 4));

        return assumedFolderSchoolIds;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestCollector
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUpdateCollectorSchoolIds()
    {
        //здесь нужна помощь
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы протестировать метод `UpdateCollectorSchoolIds()` мне необходимо симитировать возвращение методом `GetFolderSchoolIds()` коллекции `IEnumerable<string>`, которая бы содержала, к примеру:

```
{"0001", "0002", "0286"}
```

А дальше с помощью этой коллекции я бы протестировал `UpdateCollectorSchoolIds()`.

*метод GetFolderSchoolIds() содержит не меняющийся код, поэтому он (код) вынесен в отдельный метод, соблюдая open/closed*.

Как мне теперь замокать вызов GetFolderSchoolIds()?

*- не стал тестировать отдельно этот метод, так как хорошие люди объяснили, что концептуально не правильно пытаться тестировать внутренние методы класса.*

Также знаю, что строки на подобии `$@"~/Files/{_id}/collector` дышат антипаттерном. Но так и не разобрался до конца в какой части кода вставлять `пути` при работе класса с файловой системой.

Функционал класса таков:

Каждый коллектор (сборщик файлов) имеет свою папку, которая определена по пути 
`~/Files/{_id}/collector`, где id - это id коллектора. При каждом новой сборке информации создается свой новый коллектор. Коллектор просматривает (с помощью `GetFolderSchoolIds`) свою папку на наличие поступивших файлов и на основе этой информации обновляет данные в БД. Вот как-раз таки правильность **обновления данных в БД** я и хочу протестировать. Но сначала мне нужно разобраться с `GetFolderSchoolIds` - получить от него какой-нибудь список.

Я также подозреваю, что у меня класс `Collector`  не правильно спроектирован по принципам `SOLID` - может надо произвести какой-то `dependency inversion` переменной 
`folderSchoolIds`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос: `Как мне теперь замокать вызов GetFolderSchoolIds()?`

Варианты решения:

1. Код метода `GetFolderSchoolIds()` представить в виде интерфейса `IFolderSchoolIds`, который подавать в виде аргумента `Collector`. Тогда вы сможете подавать как "боевые" так и тестовые реализации интерфейса.
2. Метод `GetFolderSchoolIds()` поместить как `protected`. Далее вы сможете реализовать класс наследник в тестовых целях в котором переопределить `GetFolderSchoolIds()` таким образом, каким вам нужно.

Рекомендация: Прочитайте книгу "The Art of Unit Testing With Examples in .NET", Roy Osherove. Это одна из самых лучших книг по модульному тестированию!